# data extraction from pop-up window

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Tried to extract data from "view phone number" pop-up window but getting error

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
for count in  range(1,2):
r = requests.get('https://www.docmed360.com/mumbai/general-physician?page='+str(count),headers={'User-Agent':'Googleboat'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

for data in soup.find_all('div',class_='listing-item text-left'):
    link = data.find('div',class_='col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 title')
    link1 = link.find('a')
    links ="https://www.docmed360.com"+link1['href']
    r1 = requests.get(links)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text,'lxml')

    data1 = soup1.find('div',class_='container-fluid tab-pane')
    data2 = data1.find('table',class_='table details-table')
    data3 = data2.find_all('tr')
    for tr1 in data3[0:1]:
        print(tr1.text)
    for tr2 in data3[1:2]:
        print(tr2.text)        
    for tr3 in data3[2:3]:
        print(tr3.text)
```

here in the above code using 'tr3' for 'view phone number' which reopens as popup window ,trying to extract from that popup window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract from script tags

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
    for count in  range(1,3):
        r = s.get(f'https://www.docmed360.com/mumbai/general-physician?page={count}')
        soup = bs(r.content)
        data = [json.loads(i.text) for i in soup.select('[type="application/ld+json"]')]
        for person in data:
            keys = person.keys()
            if 'telephone' in keys:
                print(person['name'],person['telephone'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.I have one more doubt if there are more than one contact then how should i edit this code? @QHarr

Comment: Can you provide me an example please?

Comment: consider there is a list of alternate numbers from the above code we are getting only first number if i have to extract all list then how to do it? @QHarr

Comment: you would add a test for that key in the dict (Assuming under another key) and then add to the print line. Depending on whether there should always be both keys or not you use AND in the if line or you use multiple ifs or a try catch. Better than you look to see if you can find an actual instance of this and provide the associated url.